# convert str to list in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a python str object like this and i want to convert this into a list

```
l = "['Incorrect password.$', 'Login failed']"  --- type <str>
```

expected output

```
l = ['Incorrect password.$', 'Login failed']  ---- type <list>
```

Trial 1:

```
p = list(l)
```

it makes `l` as `['[', "'", 'I', 'n', 'c', 'o', 'r', 'r', 'e', 'c', 't', ' ', 'p', 'a', 's', 's', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'd', '.', '$', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'L', 'o', 'g', 'i', 'n', ' ', 'f', 'a', 'i', 'l', 'e', 'd', "'", ']']`

Trial 2:

```
  l.split(',')
```

second method is not favourable as the list element itself may contain comma in between.

How should i proceed?
Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Well, you'd `eval()` that string if you want to interpret it as if it was actually python code... but why are you doing this?

Comment: if every string you want is in between this ‘ you can parse it. and check that character if it is escaped every time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the **[ast](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)** module

```
import ast
l = "['Incorrect password.$', 'Login failed']"
print l, type(l)
l =  ast.literal_eval(l)
print l, type(l)
```

**Output:**

```
['Incorrect password.$', 'Login failed'] <type 'str'>
['Incorrect password.$', 'Login failed'] <type 'list'>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
eval(l)
```

`eval()` is a built-in function that will evaluate the code.